# Floating button inside caption

Tags: css

I am trying to create a button inside the caption of a table. It works in both Firefox and Chrome, but not IE 7 (The most used browser for my userbase). IE 7 creates the button on a new line below instead of floating it to the right.

Here is the (simplified) html

```
<table>
   <caption>
      Versions
      <button class="inline-button">Add</button>
   </caption>
   <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Description</th>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>10.0</td>
      <td>Oompa-loompa</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>10.0</td>
      <td>Oompa-loompa</td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

Here is the css:

```
button.inline-button {
    float: right;
    border: 1px solid gray;
    margin: 0;
}

table { width: 300px; }

caption { background: #ddd; }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As is usual (for IE7) one simple solution is to switch the order of the text and the `button`:

```
<caption>
   <button class="inline-button">Add</button>
   Versions
</caption>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/hgNdK/

Answer (score 1):

If you `float: left;` the "Versions" bit, it works sensibly in IE6 and IE7. I also set `display: inline;` on the button, because you are trying to make it display in-line. It *shouldn't* make any difference because of the floating, but it more semantically correct, and it may help in certain browsers.

Here's a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CEE8b/1/) demonstrating the solution.

Comment: Thanks @thirtydot. I figured that this solution is semantically more appropriate than re-ordering the button and text. It keeps them in the same order as they actually appear. Also, with the re-ordering solution, Someone who doesn't know why it's that way around may come along and "fix" it... causing the problem to appear again.

Comment: That's all true, though how much it actually matters is debatable. By the way, in your solution, the `caption` is completely hidden in WebKit browsers. You need to contains the floats (not that it matters now, but for future reference).

Comment: Thanks @thirtydot, I hadn't cross browser tested it.